# how to make middleware on spesific routes in ElysiaJS?

Tags: typescript, backend, middleware, bun

I attempted to use ElysiaJS for creating a backend server and encountered an issue while attempting to implement middleware functionality that similar to Express. I try to set the middleware on a route like this:

```
export const authRoutes = new Elysia()
    .group("/auth", app => {
        return app
            .group("/login", app => {
                return app
                    .post("/sso", ssoMiddleware, async () => {
                        console.log("now inside sso")
                    })
            })
    })
```

and there is an error in the ssoMiddleware that says

```
Argument of type '(req: any, res: any, next: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LocalHandler<TypedSchema<never>, { error: {}; request: {}; store: {}; schema: {}; meta: { schema: {}; defs: {}; exposed: {}; }; }, "/auth/login/sso">'.
  Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 3 or more, but got 1.ts(2345)
```

and inside the ssoMiddleware file is like this:

```
export const ssoMiddleware = (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {

    console.log("running the sso middleware")

    next();
}
```

So what is the correct way to implement middleware like express in ElysiaJS? I look in the documentation but its seems no mention middleware in it.

Answer (score 3):

Middlewares in elysia seems to be bit different from express, you can't just add middleware before handler function because route accepts only one [handler](https://elysiajs.com/essential/handler.html#handler) `app.post(path, handler, hook?)`.

You should use [hooks](https://elysiajs.com/essential/life-cycle.html#hook) instead.

```js
return app.post("/sso", async () => {
        console.log("now inside sso")
    }, {
     beforeHandle: ssoMiddleware
})
```

Keep in mind hooks have not the same attributes as express (req, res, next) so you need to refactor ssoMiddleware function, elysia use only one attribute in callback([Context](https://elysiajs.com/life-cycle/before-handle.html#before-handle)).

If you need to use middleware for multiple endpoints, you can use [guard](https://elysiajs.com/life-cycle/before-handle.html#guard).

Comment: What about writing a plugin? https://elysiajs.com/plugins/overview.html